# How to customize foreign key column name using Entity Framework Code-first

Tags: ef-code-first

I have the following model

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

When I generate the database schema from this using EF Code first it creates the following tables:

### Foo

- Id (PK, int, not null)

### Bar

- Id (PK, int, not null)
- Foo_Id (FK, int null)

Is it possible to change the name of the Foo_Id foreign key using attributes?

**EDIT: Here is the version that does what I need:**

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AssignedToBarId")]
    public IList<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int AssignedToBarId { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it can be done like below:

<del>protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.Entity.Map(c => c.MapKey(u => u.Id, "AssignedToBarID"));
    }</del>

Or maybe:

```
[ForeignKey("AssignedToBarID")]
public IList<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
```

NOTE: I have not tested neither of them. These are just suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, your second option did the trick! (must remember to add a property on the Bar type called AssignedToBarId for this to work)

Comment: This is a good solution if you don't need bi-directional navigation. NOTE: The name, AssignedToBarID, is a bit confusing for me; AssignedToFooID would be more illustrative.