# Change columns names on an autogenerated N:M table using EF Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm developing a Class library using C# using the latest version of Entity Framework and VS2010. I have this class:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public String City { get; set; }
    public String Country { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }
    public String InterestIn { get; set; }

    public List<User> Friends { get; set; }
    public List<User> FromWhomIsFriend { get; set; }
    public List<Activity> WantsToDo { get; set; }
    public List<Message> MessagesSent { get; set; }
    public List<Message> MessagesReceived { get; set; }
}
```

EF has generated these two tables on SQLEXPRESS:

[image]

I have three questions:

1. How can I rename the table `dbo.UserUsers` to `dbo.UserFriends`?
2. How can I rename its two columns to `UserId` and `FriendId`?
3. How can I set columns `UserId` and `FriendId` as PK for `dbo.UserFriends` table?

**NOTE:** This is my first time working with EF Code First.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest option is to create this table in your model. If EF detect such table it won't create another one.
To customize column name look here: [How to customize foreign key column name using Entity Framework Code-first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700645/how-to-customize-foreign-key-column-name-using-entity-framework-code-first)