# EF code first - custom foreign key constraint name

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I wonder if there is any chance to change name of foreign key *constraint* generated by Entity Framework when using code first.

I have two entities - `User` and `Group` - with many-to-many relationship so there is an association table `GroupUser`. Unfortunately, auto-generated foreign key constraints are named `FK_dbo.GroupUser_dbo.User_User_UserId` and `FK_dbo.GroupUser_dbo.Group_Group_GroupId`.

I would like to have foreign key constraints called like `FK_GroupUser_UserId` and `FK_GroupUser_GroupId`. That looks much cleaner to me.

Comment: Try
[how-to-customize-foreign-key-column...][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700645/how-to-customize-foreign-key-column-name-using-entity-framework-code-first

Comment: That is only how to set custom column name not foreign key name. There is plenty of questions and answers on customizing foreign key column name but I didn't find any on customizing foreign name itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not possible to customize the foreign key constraint name with data annotations or `DbModelBuilder` Fluent API. However, you can control the name with code-based migrations.

- First option: When the tables get created via migrations:

  The migration code that gets automatically generated for the join table would look like this:

  ```
  public partial class MyMigration : DbMigration
  {
      public override void Up()
      {
          CreateTable("GroupUser",
              c => new
              {
                  UserId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                  GroupId = c.Int(nullable: false),
              })
          .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.GroupId })
          .ForeignKey("User", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
          .ForeignKey("Group", t => t.GroupId, cascadeDelete: true)
          .Index(t => t.UserId)
          .Index(t => t.GroupId);

          // ...
      }
  }
  ```

  Here you can modify the two `ForeignKey` method calls to set a custom constraint name before you call `update-database`:

  ```
          .ForeignKey("User", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true,
              name: "FK_GroupUser_UserId")
          .ForeignKey("Group", t => t.GroupId, cascadeDelete: true,
              name: "FK_GroupUser_GroupId")
  ```
- Second option: When the tables already exist you can drop the constraint and add a new renamed one in a migration:

  ```
  public partial class MyMigration : DbMigration
  {
      public override void Up()
      {
          DropForeignKey("UserGroup", "UserId", "User");
          DropForeignKey("UserGroup", "GroupId", "Group");

          AddForeignKey("UserGroup", "UserId", "User",
              name: "FK_GroupUser_UserId");
          AddForeignKey("UserGroup", "GroupId", "Group",
              name: "FK_GroupUser_GroupId")

          // ...
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: How do I drop the foreign key if its already got a custom name, as the script generated uses the field names and so it doesnt get dropped because it doesnt enter the if statement

Comment: @AlanBall this is late, but to drop a foreign key with custom name, use DropForeignKey("TableName", "ForeignKeyName")

Answer (score 3):

You can implement a custom sql generator class derived from `SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator` from `System.Data.Entity.SqlServer`

For more datail plese see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31553476/4275342)