# How can I control the naming used when mapping foreign keys where there are more than one list of same class contained

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; private set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
}
```

Creates `People` table:

`ID | PersonName | School_ID | School_ID1`

```
public class School
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; private set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Person> Students { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Person> Teachers { get; set; }
}
```

Creates `Schools` table:

`ID | SchoolName`

Using the above simple model, **Entity Framework** (using **v6.0**) creates **two FK**s on `People` table as expected. The mapping is fine - it works, but it doesn't look nice on the database and would prefer to have the **FK**s called

`School_Teacher_ID, School_Student_ID`

Any help, very much appreciated.

ADDITIONAL NOTE:
I know I can use the **ForeignKey DataAnnotation** (on `School`), but this requires me to add the **FK** (on `Person`) which is leaking storage concerns into the model and adds overhead that simply isn't necessary.

To expand slightly on the overhead:
In the example I was creating to understand this I also created other classes that contained `List<Person>` (e.g. Club->Members, Company->Employees) and to employ the FK DA I would need to add an additional property for each of the classes using `List<Person>` on Person.

e.g.
Company_Employee_ID, Club_Member_ID, School_Student_ID, School_Teacher_ID

LINK to code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ataer5zndo0c6bc/Program.cs?dl=0

CONCLUSION SO FAR:
Until I get a better understanding of Fluent API my best option looks to be editing the create code produced by enabling Migrations.

Comment: exact duplicate of [EF code first - custom foreign key constraint name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926413/ef-code-first-custom-foreign-key-constraint-name) - except for EF version 5/6.

Comment: you may also be interested in this feature: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1418 it'd be the best thing for that, however, it's currently in "proposed" state. Maybe they'll add that in future EF versions.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl The proposed item looks interesting, but I can't make the first response an answer because that post is for Foreign Key Constraint names - I'm just after the FK column name which is looking like I can't do the way I want (keeping a clean model) until I start using migrations

Comment: Oooh sorry, I must have messed this up. I somehow read that you are asking for the constraint names. Sorry once again, close-vote removed!!

Comment: Personally, I think that adding a FK DataAnnotation is not that much different from adding the `Key/Required/Stringlength(100)` annotations, which also adds storage-specific data to your model.

Comment: You can use [fluent mapping](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15595818/861716) in the DAL assembly if you don't want to use attributes. (Note that the code in the question is in a `EntityTypeConfiguration` instance).

Comment: I completely agree @NateKerkhofs, but with the extra properties required as clarified in question I feel it is a step too far

Comment: @GertArnold I have been trying that route for some time, but all the examples I find have an inverse navigation element and don't use an optional List - they don't match my scenario.