# Entity Framework Primary/Foreign constraint name

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, constraints, entity-framework-migrations

Is there any way to rename a primary/foreign key constraint name through either data annotations or fluent API?

I'm not talking about the property/column name. The constraint name. I did some search and didn't find any solutions yet.

Please help!

Comment: You can do this in an `Up` [migration](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17929867/314291)

Comment: Yeah. I know. But is that the only way? I mean there's gotta be some way through fluent API when defining primary keys right?

Comment: Seemingly you can also go as far as [overriding the SqlGenerator conventions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31553476/314291)

Comment: @StuartLC thanks! That'll work, although that's a bit code overload. I was hoping for a simple solution. Migration is the way..!

Answer (score 1):

with .HasConstraintName
like you can see in the underlying example

```
entity.HasOne(d => d.Director)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Movie)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.DirectorId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Movie_Person");
```

Comment: is it possible with EF6?

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to customize the foreign key constraint name with `Data annotations` or `Fluent API`.

There is some options that you can follow:

- [Implement a custom sql generator class derived from `SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator` from `System.Data.Entity.SqlServer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31534945/change-foreign-key-constraint-naming-convention/31553476#31553476)
- [When the tables get created via migrations, the migration code that gets automatically generated, so you can set a custom constraint name(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17929867/3367974)
- [When the tables already exist you can drop the constraint and add a new renamed one in a migration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17929867/3367974)