# Issue with 1 to 1 shared primary key relationship

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework, code-first

I am using EF 6 code first. I have a following situation in a database design:

I have 3 tables i.e.

- Student
- Person
- Contact

Through code first Fluent API i have established a uni-directional 1 to 1 mapping between the following:

- Student - Contact
- Person - Contact

When i established the relationship between **Student - Contact** everything is perfectly working. But when i added the next relationship i.e. between **Person - Contact** then i got the following exception:

> The operation failed because an index or statistics with name 'IX_Id' already exists on table 'dbo.Contacts'.

Now i know that because of shared primary key concept the Primary key of **Contact** is the FK of **Student** and then when i added the new relationship i.e. between **Person - Contact** force the EF to create the new FK for **Person** and because the FK with the same name already exist which cause the exception.

I want to know that is there any workaround for this situation ??

*I have to keep the **contact** table separate because lots of other tables in my database like Student, Person, Firm, etc have there contact information stored in contact table. So i have to create a lot of other 1 to 1 relationship with contact also.*

Comment: can you post the schema definitions?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/5700825/880990 helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing entity framework or code first, I think the issue would be that your tables need to look like this:

```
Contact:  
   contact_id primary_key

Person:  
    person_id primary_key
    contact_id foreign_key

Student:  
    student_id primary_key
    contact_id foreign_key
```

Based on the error message it would appear you are trying to do something like this:

```
Contact:  
       contact_id primary_key
       person_student_id foreign_key -- either to Person or Student
    Person:  
        person_id primary_key
        contact_id foreign_key

    Student:  
        student_id primary_key
        contact_id foreign_key
```